# Mongoose child schema in an array: calculate default value from parent schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to make the below construction work? Currently, I am able to do what I need by simply defining the necessary fields directly inside the child schema. However, since the same information is repeated across all child documents within the array, I would like to know if I can roll up this information to the top level.

If I simply define a nested schema, it fails to calculate the default value with `ValidationError: records.0.d: Path "d" is required.`

```js
const childSchema = new Schema({
  c: Number,
  d: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: function () {
      // the part I need help with
      return this.parent.a + this.parent.b + this.c;
    }
  }
});

const parentSchema = new Schema({
  a: Number,
  b: Number,
  records: [childSchema]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parent()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.parent()) instead like this:

```js
const childSchema = new Schema({
  c: Number,
  d: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: function () {
      return this.parent().a + this.parent().b + this.c;
    }
  }
});
```